# iron:router + alanning:roles => why this role check working randomly?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm using iron:router and alanning:roles and I want to restrict my *SecretArea* for only users who has been added to admin role. This works just fine if user is not logged in. But if user has logged in and she is an admin then the trouble starts.

I can get Meteor.userId() on every page load which is made against *SecreArea*. The problem is **Roles.userIsInRole** sometimes it returns true and sometimes false. It doesn't make much sense..

And this is ofc really annoying for users who know they should have admin rights and still this is routing them pretty much randomly. I think the ratio here is something like 90-10 percents, most of time it's working, but one time out of ten its not.

Not sure, but this could be mostly happening when made changes to code and meteor reloads.

```
SecretAreaController = RouteController.extend({
    layoutTemplate: 'secretAreaLayout',
    onBeforeAction: function () {
        if (!Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), ['admin']))
            Router.go('/');
        else
            this.next();
    }
});
```

Worth of mentioning: all SecreArea routes are extending this controller.

Packages I'm using for this:

- [alanning:roles](https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles/)
- [iron:router](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router)

So am I doing something wrong in here, or is there better solution for this?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After few frustrating hours later this solved the problem for me.

```
SecretAreaController = RouteController.extend({
    layoutTemplate: 'secretAreaLayout',
    waitOn: function () {
        return [ Meteor.subscribe("roles") ];
    },
    onBeforeAction: function () {
        if (!Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), ['admin']))
            Router.go('/');
        else
            this.next();
    }
});
```

And on server side publication:

```
Meteor.publish("roles", function (){ 
    return Meteor.roles.find({});
});
```

In documentaion of [alanning:roles](https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles) says "The currently logged-in user's roles field is automatically published to the client.". I think there was some kind of timing issue with this one and that caused this problem. Because after adding waitOn the problem just disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

`Meteor.userId()` is [reactive data source](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_userid). When first time app load, meteor execute logging in process. So you should check also `Meteor.loggingIn()`.

I don't know `iron:router` well. You should do `if (Meteor.loggingIn()) {//wait}` something like that, on one of hooks.

Comment: I don't see how this is helping anyway in this situation. Those times when Roles.userIsInRole returns false, Meteor.userId() returns the right userID. So the problem can't be that one?

Comment: hmmm. Interesting. Can you at least test this code. `if (!Meteor.loggingIn() && !Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), ['admin']))`

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, the main issue is the timing of when the roles data is available on the client.  Here is a sequence diagram from a recent [presentation](http://slides.com/alanning55/a-pattern-for-flowrouter-auth#/) I did that illustrates what's happening:

[image: timing of meteor authentication and authorization]

One way to resolve this is to have the router block until all the data is available.  That works but its not an ideal user experience.

The best way to handle this is to not perform auth checks in the router but rather to do them at the template-level.  FlowRouter forces you to do it template-level but IronRouter is more lenient.  Arunoda did a great write-up about it in his [Meteor Routing Guide](https://kadira.io/academy/meteor-routing-guide/content/implementing-auth-logic-and-permissions).

Here are a couple of examples which show template-level auth in action:

- https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles/tree/master/examples/flow-router
- https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles/tree/master/examples/flow-router-advanced

These examples use FlowRouter but the same principle can be applied to IronRouter just as easily.